# Boolean data-* Attributes

Tags: javascript, html

Can you use `data-*` attributes as boolean attributes?  If not, is there an alternative?

For example, you can have

```
<input disabled>
```

It would be helpful in some cases to have

```
<input data-on>
```

Using `data-on="true"` or `data-on=""` is not desirable -- the *presence* of the attribute should indicate its boolean value.

Comment: Essentially `data-on` is `data-on=""`, using jQuery you can simply do `$("input").is("[data-on]");`

Comment: note: var t=document.createElement("input");
t.disabled=true;
t.outerHTML == '<input disabled="">';
  so i would say no, but you can serialize the HTML differently than the browser...

Comment: The *presence* of the attribute should indicate its boolean value: `typeof element.dataset.on !== 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can indeed use `data-*` attributes *as if* they were boolean attributes - however, as far as `dataset` is concerned `<input data-on>` is equivalent of `<input data-on="">`.  This means that unlike `required` or other boolean attributes you won't be able to do this:

```
<input class="some-class" data-on required>

var elementOfInterest = document.querySelector(".some-class");
if (elementOfInterest.dataset.on) {
    // We will never get here because dataset.on === ""
    // and "" == false
}

if (elementOfInterest.required) {
    // We *do* get here because required is a boolean attribute
}
```

Instead you'll need to do an explicit check against undefined:

```
if (elementOfInterest.dataset.on !== undefined) {
    // We will get here because "" !== undefined
}
```

This gives you no way of distinguishing between `data-on` and `data-on=""`, but if you are treating it as a boolean attribute, they both add up to the same thing anyway (only the absence of the attribute indicates falsity.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `data-*` attributes can function as boolean attributes, at least as far as the DOM and browser selector engines are concerned: http://jsfiddle.net/MhJNb/

I haven't tested compatibility, but Chrome has no problem with applying `div[data-on]` rules to `<div data-on></div>`.