# Filter NodeList by CSS3 selector

Tags: javascript

I have a NodeList object - let's say, returned by $element.children - and I would like to filter it by a CSS3 selector to only have certain elements left which meet my criteria. The function should basically look as following:

```js
var filter = (function($elementsToFilter, selector){
   var $elementsFiltered;
   // ...?
   return $elementsFiltered;
});
filter(document.querySelector('#element').children, '.two.three')
```

```html
<div id="element">
   <div class="one two three">Yes</div>
   <div class="two three">Yes</div>
   <div class="two">No</div>
   <div class="three">No</div>
</div>
```

1. Might this not be useful for production (Bad practice)?
2. What is the fastest way to dynamically select the elements with 'Yes' in the 'filter' function?

Please note, that I am NOT looking for a framework solution, e.g. in jQuery. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 1:

You most efficient method I can think of *without using `document.querySelector()`* is to use the `contains()` function on [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
for (elem in document.getElementById('element').children) {
  if (elem.classList.contains('two') && elem.classList.contains('three')) {
     // Do something
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could merge your selectors into one like this:

```js
for (elem in document.querySelector('#element > .two.three')) {
  // Do something
}
```

#### Question 2:

If you control the server-side code which generates this HTML, you may find it easier to use a data attribute like this:

```html
<div id="element">
  <div class="one two three" data-select>Yes</div>
  <div class="two three" data-select>Yes</div>
  <div class="two">No</div>
  <div class="three">No</div>
</div>
```

Then with similar options to question 1:

```js
for (elem in document.getElementById('element').children) {
  if (elem.dataset.select !== undefined) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

*The explicit check for `undefined` is necessary here ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006946/1813169)).*

```js
for (elem in document.querySelector('#element > [data-select]') {
  // Do something
}
```

---

As an aside, javascript now has the [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. You can use this with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to replace your homebrew `filter` function (example taken from my first code snippet):

```js
let filtered = Array.from(document.getElementById('element').children).filter(elem => {
  return elem.classList.contains('two') && elem.classList.contains('three');
});
```

Or create a `filterByClasses` function:

```
function filterByClasses(elements, classes) {
  return Array.from(elements).filter(elem => {
    return !classes.map(elem.classList.contains).includes(false);
  }
}

// Usage:
let filtered = filterByClasses(
                 document.getElementById('#element').children,
                 ['two', 'three']
               );
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. After reflecting your answer and thinking about other possibilities, I ask myself: Would it be faster to implement a matchesCssSelector function which more or less includes your filterByClasses function - or is it better to have a $('#element') function to select elements and store the CSS selector in the returned NodeList's prototype attribute, because it could be reused when calling .children('.two.three') which would actually not use the JavaScript .children attribute but concat the element's CSS selector and the children selector (with a ' > ' in between)?

Comment: So you would only have to parse for commas in the children CSS selector instead of ALL CSS selectors, including things like :checked etc. This solution would work as long as you implement things like .parent('.two.three'), because there is no CSS selector for that. Seems to be quite tricky..

Comment: If you write a `matchesCssSelector` function, you may as well just use `document.querySelector()` - that’s what it’s for. `filterByClasses` is designed to be *more efficient* than just using a query selector by only supporting classes. If all you want is a powerful DOM manipulation library, I suggest using jQuery instead of trying to roll your own. That’s what it’s designed for.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain the matchesCssSelector function enough. It should check whether a certain element matches a CSS selector. The .children('.two.three') function could base on that and use your suggested method Array.filter() with the JS .children attribute. But again, that would require a parser for CSS selectors which I don't really want to build.

| Another idea is to get all children ($element.children) - and get all sub-elements which match the CSS selector ($element.querySelectorAll('.two.three')). Then filter the children for match with selected sub-elements. Performance?

Comment: What’s your overall goal here? Why is it necessary to check for CSS selectors after you’ve already selected the element?

Comment: The goal is to automatize selecting the parent(s)/children of an element via CSS selector in the most performant way. It is necessary to do this, because a function could for example need to select certain children of an element, which has been passed as a parameter.

Comment: You can already use [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to “find” children via CSS selectors. And if your page hierarchy is designed correctly, there should never be a need to search for parent elements. Instead, try to refractor code up to reference the nearest common parent in the DOM tree. If absolutely necessary to traverse up, pass parent references down through callbacks.

Comment: I looked into how jQuery forms the dollar selector return. It is an object with all the methods; and the elements as values of numeric keys: $('selector') => { 0: element1, 1: element2, each: function1, filter: function2 }